# IP range of kinesis.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com

Tags: amazon-web-services, ip, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I need kinesis.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com ’s ip range. I could’t find any documents about ip range for kinesis. E.g. : I can find the ip ranges of s3 in https://ip-ranges.amazonaws.com/ip-ranges.json . But kinesis not. Is there a way to search it? I check kinesis.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com from my browser and it returns 99.80.34.xxx ip adresses for all. So I think it can be 99.80.34.0/24 ip ranges , right?

Comment: I have found the solution, I pinged the address repeatedly. It returned me on 99.80.34.128/25 ip range for all. The first 5 ip addresses is belonged to AWS in remember, the least returned ip address was 99.80.34.132. So it means that the ip range of kinesis.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com is 99.80.34.128/25. Then I checked the IP documentation of aws on https://ip-ranges.amazonaws.com/ip-ranges.json . The ip range was belonged to AMAZON service on eu-west-1 location.